# Javascript object attribute is accessible but gives undefined error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to work with data sent from a server using the following code where `msg` is the incoming data that holds two arrays:

```
console.log(msg);
for (var i = 0; i <= msg.cues.length; i++) {
  $("#cues").append("<div class=\"cue-item\" cueval=\"cue-" + i + "\"><h4>"+msg.cues[i].name+"</h4>"+msg.cues[i].description+"</div>");
}
```

This code adds the required elements to the page and everything seems to be fine from the browser window, but in the console I get the below error that blocks all other code from running:

```
{…}
  channels: Array [ 0, 0, 0, … ]
  cues: […]
    0: Object { name: "Cue 1", description: "This is a test cue" }
```

`TypeError: msg.cues[i] is undefined`

Any idea why this is happening and how I can solve this issue?

Comment: The `for` statement is wrong, it should be `for (var i = 0; i < msg.cues.length; i++)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're iterating one position past the length of the array. Change

```
for (var i = 0; i <= msg.cues.length; i++)
```

to

```
for (var i = 0; i < msg.cues.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `<=` to `<` in for-loop head